# Jquery dynamic toggle problem

Tags: jquery, toggle

I wrote this jquery which toggles each block. But when you toggle one the rest also toggles.

How can i dynamicaly toggle(show/hide) each block independently, so when i toggle in one section it doesnt toggle the other section.

NOTE : I cant rename each class for the block, since its being dynamically cloned.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.alternatepayee-b').hide();  

  $('.alternatepayee-checkbox').click(function() {  
    $('.alternatepayee-b').slideToggle("slow");    
  });    
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="alternatepayee-checkbox clearfix">
  <input type="checkbox" value="y" name="subscribe" id="checkbox_4">
  <label class="foreign" for="checkbox_4" >Alternate Payee</label>
</div>
<div class="alternatepayee-b clearfix" >                
  <label class="field-accoundtid  arrow">Account ID
    <input type="text" name="accountid" value="" /></label>  
  <label class="field-first arrow" >First Name
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" /></label>
  <label class="field-last arrow">Last Name
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" /></label>           
</div>

<!-- 2nd block -->
<div class="alternatepayee-checkbox clearfix">
  <input type="checkbox" value="y" name="subscribe" id="checkbox_4"> 
  <label class="foreign" for="checkbox_4" >Alternate Payee</label>
</div>
<div class="alternatepayee-b clearfix" >            
  <label class="field-accoundtid arrow">Account ID
    <input type="text" name="accountid" value="" /></label>  
  <label class="field-first arrow" >First Name
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" /></label>
  <label class="field-last arrow">Last Name
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" /></label>           
</div>
```

Comment: Note: it's not valid to have multiple elements with the same id (`checkbox_4`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery selectors work on *sets* of elements. You need to refine the selector in your click event handler so it only works on the *one* desired element. Something (approximately) like this should work:

```
$('.alternatepayee-checkbox').click(function() {
  // 'this' refers to the single checkbox div that was actually clicked
  // next looks for the next sibling that matches '.alternatepayee-b'
  $(this).next('.alternatepayee-b').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

What you use for [`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) will vary depending on your markup but that's the general idea.

Also, if you are adding these dynamically, you can use [`.live('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead to automatically bind your event handler to elements added after your page loads.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there anyway to may it a function so i can use it any place?

Comment: This is pretty standard for a jquery one-liner so I wouldn't worry too much about reusing it all that much.